# Fatal error Xcode 8 Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

ok guys can I get a little help with my code. When running the app I get an error is there any way to fix this problem?

```
let fileUrl = dict["fileUrl"]as! String
let url = NSURL(string: fileUrl)
let data = NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL!)
let picture = UIImage(data: data! as Data!)
let photo = JSQPhotoMediaItem(image: picture)
self.messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderName, media: photo))
```

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GeW9.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift

Comment: You should use `if let` to check for the optional instead of force unwrap it using `!`.

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting the correct url in fileUrl ? Also check if the data is nil or not

Comment: where can i check if I'm using the fileUrl?

Answer (score 1):

Here I see 4 big fat problems with your code.

1. You are force casting the value of `fileUrl` of the dictionary `dict` to `String`. If your dictionary doesn't have the value for `fileUrl`, or if it's not castable to string, your code will crash. You should change that to optional cast like:

   `if let fileUrl = dict["fileUrl"] as? String
   {
   //your code if you have fileUrl
   }`
2. When creating the url to the file, you are using the wrong initialization method, you should be using this:

   `let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: fileUrl)`
3. After you have the url to the file, you should also check if you have the data of the file, because `contentsOfFile:` initializer of the `NSData` returns the optional object, which may be `nil`, so another `if` check:
   `if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url) {\\ code with the data}`
4. `init?(data: Data)` initializer of the `UIImage` also returns optional object, so if the required by latter code, you should also check if you have the image or `nil` with if statement.

The result code should be something like:

```
if let fileUrl = dict["fileUrl"] as? String {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: fileUrl)
            if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url) {
                let image = UIImage(data: data as Data) // you can cast NSData to Data without force or optional casting
                let photo = JSQPhotoMediaItem(image: image)
                self.messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderName, media: photo))
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the first line of code with this line for optional binding check :-

```
guard let fileUrl = dict["fileUrl"] as! String else {return}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo should do validation in cases where the variable may be nil, the following is an example:

```
if let fileUrl = dict["fileUrl"] as? String {
    let url = URL(string: fileUrl)
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
        let picture = UIImage(data: data)
        let photo = JSQPhotoMediaItem(image: picture)
        self.messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderName, media: photo))
    } catch {

    }
}
```

Comment: While solving 2 issues with code, your code doesn't solve other problems. Please, pay more attention when you are helping with code.

Comment: @FahriAzimov I haven't tested my code, could you point the problems this solution may have?